# Check if DB is developed using unicode

Tags: postgresql, unicode

How do we check if the database is unicode. I am using postgresql and I need to know if it is unicode.

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no such thing as "developed using" unicode.

If you want to know the database encoding, use:

```
SELECT current_setting('server_encoding');
```

which reports the database encoding of the current database. Or to get it for any database:

```
select pg_catalog.pg_encoding_to_char(d.encoding) 
from pg_database d
where datname = 'mydatabase';
```

You might also be interested in the collation, see `psql`'s `\l` output for details, and to see the query that produces it run `psql -E` then `\l`.

Comment: I got SELECT current_setting('server_encoding'); as UTF-8, and according to http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/multibyte.html It shows unicode. Thanks again :)